# Spreadsheet Project with Winforms, Unable to Copy File error

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, dll

I'm working on a simple Excel project for a Software Engineering class. This is my first time writing a DLL and using INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm getting these errors:

Error   13  Could not copy "SpreadsheetEngine\bin\Debug\SpreadsheetEngine.dll" to "bin\Debug\SpreadsheetEngine.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed."

Error   14  Unable to copy file "SpreadsheetEngine\bin\Debug\SpreadsheetEngine.dll" to "bin\Debug\SpreadsheetEngine.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\SpreadsheetEngine.dll' because it is being used by another process."

These errors have really set me back and I'd appreciate any help with figuring them out.

Here is my DLL class:

```
 namespace SpreadsheetEngine
    {
    public abstract class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int RowIndex;
        private int ColumnIndex;
        protected string Text;
        protected string Value;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //implement property changed notification
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    //Text property is a getter and setter for member variable
    public string CellText
    {
        get
        { return this.Text; }

        set
        {
            if (Text != value)
            {
                this.Text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }

    //Value property is a string that represents the "evaluated" value.
    public string CellValue
    {
        get { return Value; }
    }

    abstract internal void SetValue(string value);


    //cell constructor sets column and row indices
    public Cell(int row_index, int column_index)
    {
        RowIndex = row_index;
        ColumnIndex = column_index;
    }

    //getters for row and column indices
    public int Row
    {
        get { return RowIndex; }
    }

    public int Column
    {
        get { return Column; }
    }
}

//this class inherits from cell so that we can instantiate and set value from inside 
public class RealCell : Cell
{
    //constructor calls the base class constructor
    public RealCell(int row_index, int column_index):base(row_index, column_index)
    {

    }


    //this is how we'll set the value property from the spreadsheet
    override internal void SetValue(string new_value)
    {
        Value = new_value;
    }
}

public class Spreadsheet 
{
    public int num_rows;
    public int num_columns;
    public RealCell[,] CellArray;

    public int ColumnCount()
    {
        return num_columns;
    }

    public int RowCount()
    {
        return num_rows;
    }


    //constructor with 2d array to hold cell objects
    public Spreadsheet(int rows, int columns)
    {
        num_rows = rows;
        num_columns = columns;

        RealCell[,] cell_array = new RealCell[num_rows, num_columns];
        //give all of the cells in our spreadsheet proper row and column indices
        for(int row = 1; row <= num_rows; row++)
        {
            //potential off by one error here at num_columns?
            for(char column = 'A'; column <= 'A' + num_columns; columns++)
            {
                RealCell cell = new RealCell(row, column);
                cell_array[row - 1, column - 65] = cell;
            }
        }
        CellArray = cell_array;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler CellPropertyChanged;

    //implement property changed notification
    //TODO: implement CellPropertyChanged event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(Cell cell, string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = CellPropertyChanged;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            handler(cell, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    void handler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RealCell cell = sender as RealCell;

        string text = cell.CellText;
        if (text[0] != '=')
        {
            cell.SetValue(text);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.SetValue(text.Substring(1, text.Length));
            OnPropertyChanged(sender as Cell, "Cell Value");
        }
    }

    //function returns RealCell object 
    public RealCell get_cell(int row_index, int column_index)
    {
        if (row_index > num_rows || column_index > num_columns)
        {
            //there is no such cell. return null.
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return CellArray[row_index - 1, column_index - 65];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That sounds like the dll is in use. Are you sure you are not running anything that would access it? E.g. if you ran your program while trying to build it, you would get that. Otherwise restart your computer for the lock to be released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was causing the issue.
When I tried to run my code, I noticed that my laptop fan was going crazy and my battery life was awful. Upon opening my task manager, I was seeing that my program was still running even after I closed Visual Studio.
Turns out I had an infinite loop here:

```
for(char column = 'A'; column <= 'A' + num_columns; columns++)
        {
            RealCell cell = new RealCell(row, column);
            cell_array[row - 1, column - 65] = cell;
        }
```

I was incrementing columns instead of column. It was one typo that gave me all this grief.

Answer (score 0):

There is an opened file handle that prevents overriding SpreadsheetEngine.dll. When you building the solution this file can't be rewriten as stated in error message. The simplest technique to resolve that is to rename SpreadsheetEngine.dll to something else (for example __SpreadsheetEngine.dll).
You can also find and close a file handle using [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).